# Inference rules demonstrate is true

Tags: logic

I have the following propositions and argument

\begin{align}
1. &  &q \to  \neg p\\
2. & &p\vee s\\
3. && \neg q \to \neg r\\
4. && r\\
\therefore &&s
\end{align}

I need to demonstrate that is true, using inference rules. But I'm stuck. Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Details depend on the proof system used...

Comment: Contrapose 3. to get $r \to q$ and apply *modus ponens* with 4. to get $q$.

Comment: I need to use inference rules.

Comment: Then *mp* again with 1. to derive $\lnot p$ and conclude with [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) from 2.

Comment: Thanks Mauro. I'm gonna try that. Could you write a complete answer with the steps? that would be very helpful. thanks

Comment: @user3032175 which inference rules do you have?  And please don't say 'the basic rules', since there are many different systems of rules. Can you indicate the rules that you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3.$ is equivalent to $r\to q$. Then put use $3$ and $4$ to prove $q$, and then use $1$ to prove $\neg p$.

Once you have $\neg p$, it should be easy to prove $s$ from $p\lor s$

Comment: I've got p v s, ¬p but I'm stuck because I don't know how to prove s

Comment: @user3032175 $p\lor s$ is the same as $\neg(\neg p)\lor s$ is the same as $\neg p\to s$.

Comment: @user3032175 Or, just use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism directly.

Comment: Ok, Now I see! thanks!